# Rails 4 filter feed items from model on home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, filter, filtering

On my website's home page I want to implement a filter. A user has many ideas. In this ideas table there is a column called "platform", in which one of these strings are stored: "iPhone Application", "Android Application" or "Web Application" to determine the type of the idea.

I want the user to be able to filter the feed items on the homepage based on platform.

I already have made the specific scopes in my ideas model (as you can see below). These scopes work, as i tested them out in the console.

**Idea Model**

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

scope :iphone, -> { where(platform: 'iPhone application') } # All iphone ideas
scope :android, -> { where(platform: 'Android application') } # All android ideas
scope :web_app, -> { where(platform: 'Web Application') } # All webapp ideas

end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ideas, dependent: :destroy

  def feed
    Idea.all
  end
end
```

**Static pages controller**  As you can see below, im doing it the easy way (a separate action for the specific platform filters) I just can't figure out how to link the action with a dropdown, or a button which load only iPhone ideas on the home page.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController 

def home
 if signed_in?
  @idea  = current_user.ideas.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end
end

def home_iphone
 if signed_in?
  @idea  = current_user.ideas.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.iphone.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end
 render "static_pages/home"
end
end
```

**Home page**  Here you can see the link to the iphone ideas (which on the moment doesn't error, but loads all ideas and not just the iPhone ideas)

```
<% if signed_in? %>
 <%= link_to "iPhone", root_path, :controller => :ideas_controller, :action =>  :home_iphone %>
 <div class="span8">
  <h3>All ideas</h3>
  <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your link_to "iphone" it has path to root_path and also your are giving controller,action explicitly. i think if you have has_many relations for ideas in user model you can directly use scope **current_user.ideas.iphone** no need to use model method feed for that purpose

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you think that in the link itself i can put the current_user.ideas.iphone? or do you mean in the controller? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: it's going to be in the controller more specific action(home_iphone)